# JSON:API error unprocessable entity status 422 entity_id this value should not be null

Tags: 8

I'm trying to post a flag with JSON:API but I'm getting the following error:

```
"errors": [
    {
        "title": "Unprocessable Entity",
        "status": "422",
        "detail": "entity_id: This value should not be null.",
        "source": {
            "pointer": "/data/attributes/entity_id"
        }
    }
```

I'm very confused because in the data I'm posting, the `entity_id` is definitely included...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) module enabled.

If you do, you or someone else may have disabled the field for the resource you are trying to POST to at `/admin/config/services/jsonapi/resource_types`.

In this case, I had disabled the `entity_id` field for my flag resource, causing the "null" error even when I posted a value with axios.